# How to print a larger-size white spade symbol to a terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, terminal, utf-8, symbols

In Python3:

`print("\u2660\uFE0F")` prints a larger size spade symbol: ♠️

`print("\u2660")` prints a white spade symbol, but considerably smaller

I want a **white spade symbol of larger size**.

Is this even possible?

Optionally: I also want a white club symbol ♣️ of larger size

Comment: I can't see _`White Club Suit`_/_`White Spade Suit`_ on terminal (supposedly rendered using too thin drawing contours?) - `♣` (U+2663,  *Black Club Suit*)
- `♦` (U+2666,  *Black Diamond Suit*)
- `♥` (U+2665,  *Black Heart Suit*)
- `♠` (U+2660,  *Black Spade Suit*)
- `♧` (U+2667,  *White Club Suit*)
- `♢` (U+2662,  *White Diamond Suit*)
- `♡` (U+2661,  *White Heart Suit*)
- `♤` (U+2664,  *White Spade Suit*)

Comment: `Unifont` or `Courier New` render all visible…

Comment: @JosefZ (U+2664, White Spade Suit) - the symbol is too small on my terminal...

Comment: And what about `\u2664\uFE0F` with _Variation Selector-16_?

Comment: @JosefZ Doesn't work either